# I'm trying to convert the time of day from military time to a 12-hour format using call by reference

Tags: c++, visual-c++

so, I'm new to calling by reference but from what I understand, its used for void functions to supply the main method with values. This is what I have.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;
void convert12Format(int& hrs, int& minutes, int& time, string& ampm);
int main() {
    int length, width, time, hrs, minutes;
    string ampm;

    convert12Format(hrs, minutes, time, ampm);

    string timeOfDay = hrs + ":" + minutes + ampm;

    cout << timeOfDay;


    return 0;
}
void convert12Format(int& hrs, int& minutes, int& time, string& ampm){
    

    cout << "Please enter the time in military time (hhmm): ";
    cin >> time;

    hrs = time / 100;
    minutes = time % 100;
    if (hrs < 12) {
    
        ampm = " AM";
    }
    else {

        hrs = hrs - 12;
    ampm = " PM"; 
    }
}
```

when inserting a time in the form (hhmm): 1233

I get an output:

PM

I was expecting:

12:33 PM

Comment: `hrs + ":"` does not do what you think it does. If you add `4` to `":"` you don't get `"4:"`. You do not add an integer value to a string, and somehow end up concatenating the two. C++ simply does not work this way, that's all. Can you explain what led you to believe this is how string concatenation works? How does your C++ textbook explain the correct approach for concatenating text strings, the the correct approach for converting integers to strings?

Comment: If you want to concat numbers and strings, either convert the numbers to `std::string` using `std::to_string()`, or else write the values to a `std::ostringstream` first, and then extract a `std::string` from it via its `str()` method. Or, in C++20 and later, you can use `std::format()` to create formatted strings from input values.

Comment: On a side note, `main()` doesn't use `time` for anything, so there is no reason for `convert12Format()` to have an `int& time` parameter at all. `time` should be a local variable inside of `convert12Format()` only.

Comment: I'm an idiot.  I for some reason was trying to concatenate the string like in java.

thanks everyone for the help. I appreciate the answer posted.

Comment: *"I'm new to calling by reference"* -- that  could explain why you called it "calling by reference" instead of "passing by reference". Not that this question has anything to do with pass-by-reference. (Test one thing at a time. Verify the values you get back with*out* trying to format them. `std::cout << hrs << '\n'; std::cout << minutes << '\n'; std::cout << ampm << '\n'; std::cout << time <<'\n';`. Add labels if desired.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on this statement:

```
string timeOfDay = hrs + ":" + minutes + ampm;
```

You are invoking **pointer arithmetic**, not **string concatenation**.

You are adding an `int` (`hrs`) to a `const char[2]` array (`":"`), which decays into a `const char*` pointer.  So, you are advancing the pointer in memory by however many characters the `int` specifies.  Which, in this case, will lead to *undefined behavior* for any `int` value other than `0` or `1`.

Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void convert12Format(int& hrs, int& minutes, string& ampm);

int main() {
    int hrs, minutes;
    string ampm;

    convert12Format(hrs, minutes, ampm);

    string timeOfDay = to_string(hrs) + ":" + to_string(minutes) + " " + ampm;
    cout << timeOfDay;

    // alternatively:
    // cout << hrs << ":" << minutes << " " + ampm;

    return 0;
}

void convert12Format(int& hrs, int& minutes, string& ampm){
    int time;

    cout << "Please enter the time in military time (hhmm): ";
    cin >> time;

    hrs = time / 100;
    minutes = time % 100;

    if (hrs < 12) {
        if (hrs == 0) hrs = 12;
        ampm = "AM";
    }
    else {
        if (hrs > 12) hrs -= 12;
        ampm = "PM"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need a separate check for `hrs == 12`, or else your noon would look funny.

Comment: @VladFeinstein Same with midnight, too. I've updated my example.